# HTML5 Local Storage Between Pages

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I am new to the HTML5/JS programming scene, but I am really trying to learn quickly... I am looking to build a site that functions like a Jeopardy game, with a home screen that has a table with categories and point values that, on click, will hyperlink to a question page.
On the homepage I was looking to keep track of the points.  I have a textbox there coded as:

```
<input type="number" id="SamTotalPoint" value="0" readonly="readonly"/>
```

On the question pages, I have placed buttons that would ideally add points to the home page using local storage.  The button is coded as:

```
<input type="button" id="SamHist50" value="Team Sam" onclick="SamScoreKeeper(samPoint,50)"/>
```

Now I'm looking to connect the two.  On an external JS, I tried to define the function as:

```
   function SamScoreKeeper(samPoint,pointsToAdd)
{
    window.localStorage.setItem("SamTotalPoint", "0");
    var SamOldScore = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("SamTotalPoint"));
    window.alert(samPoint);
    window.alert(pointsToAdd);
    samPoint = samPoint + pointsToAdd
    var SamNewScore = samPoint;
    var SamTotalv = SamOldScore + SamNewScore
    window.alert(samPoint);
    window.history.back();
    document.getElementById("SamTotalPoint").value; = SamTotalv;
}
```

I put the Which simply isn't working.  I have spent a while trying to just research this and understand it more, but after about 6-7 hours total of fighting with it and watching a bunch of tutorials, I still simply can't get it.  This page would just be run locally off of a flash drive, not actually hosted on a server, which is why I was hoping local storage could solve the problem rather than using PHP.  The window alerts are just there so I could make sure the JS was doing the arithmetic.  Can anybody help me with this?  It would be most appreciated!

Comment: `document.getElementById("SamTotalPoint").value; = SamTotalv;` an obvious typo here. Also, what are the outcomes and what were you expecting?

Comment: You actually haven't updated anything in your localStorage, so it's never set to anything except `"0"`. Also, don't expect anything meaningful to happen after calling `history.back()`; `SamTotalPoint` is on a different page and cannot be accessed by the scoring page. Use the events suggested in [Leo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778195/361762)

Comment: @E_net4 - the idea is to have the text box on the main page increase by a certain point value... in the case of this example, it should be by 50.  I must be oblivious, but I don't see the typo that you are pointing out.

Comment: @E_net4 oh my.  I'm dumb.  Nevermind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When **localStorage** is modified, a `storage` event will be fired on all **other** pages that share the storage. You just need to handle the event, and retrieve updated data. This also works for **sessionStorage**.

```
document.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
    // don't forget to take a look at the parameter - event object
    // update your page here, good luck
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now my code looks like
`document.addEventListener('SamScoreStorage', function SamScoreKeeper(samPoint,pointsToAdd)
{window.localStorage.setItem("SamTotalPoint", "0");
var SamOldScore=parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("SamTotalPoint"));
window.alert(samPoint);
window.alert(pointsToAdd);
samPoint = samPoint + pointsToAdd
var SamNewScore = samPoint;
var SamTotalv = SamOldScore + SamNewScore
window.alert(samPoint);
window.history.back();
document.getElementById("SamTotalPoint").value = SamTotalv;
}, false);`
Uncaught ReferenceError: SamScoreKeeper is not defined'.
Why is that?

Comment: @PatrickNorthcraft Here's a link to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent), you could take a look at the example code.

Comment: Thank you!  As for the reference error, I am using the latest version of Chrome (42.0.2311.90 m).  I'm still not really understanding it... maybe its just not meant to be.